# wordpress list pages function

Tags: php, wordpress

Im cutting a template I got built into wordpress, im having difficulty with the menu, I need to have the first list item( `<li>` ) that is returned from the wp_list_pages function to have value="1" in the tag as well so the jquery menu starts there, therefore  would be the first item

Comment: Could you please be more specific in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wordpress codex helps you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Answer (score 0):

You'd better user get_pages (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) so you can write your own wrapper.

If you want to focus the first navigation item with jquery, you can do it like this:

```
$('ul#nav li:first')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use PHP string manipulation methods to replace the first instance of found text with a modified version of it. For example:

```
<?php
    $navStr = wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=2&sort_column=menu_order&echo=0');
    $navStr = preg_replace('/<li class="/i', '<li value="1" class="', $navStr, 1);
    echo $navStr;
?>
```